# Clients cannot reconnect to Server using TCP Sockets

Tags: c#, sockets, tcp, client-server, asyncsocket

I have a problem with socket connection.

I have a Client and a Server application where the server application listens for clients on a particular port.

500 clients are connected and sending data to the server to be processed and everything is working fine.

At particular time, I closed all clients and also close the server. When I restart the server after 10 minutes and restart the clients 2 minutes later, very few clients (5-15) are able to reconnect.

Please give me a solution why all clients do not reconnect.

```cs
mainSocket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
endpoint = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, int.Parse(txt_server_port.Text));
mainSocket.Bind(endpoint);
mainSocket.Listen(100);
mainSocket.BeginAccept(new AsyncCallback(ConnetedClient), mainSocket);
```

Comment: You gotto show us the code, man. We need the code. Show us the code! :)

Comment: You probably have a timeout set on TcpListener, so when timeout expires, no clients can be connected... You should definitely add some code to your question...

Comment: mainSocket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp); endpoint = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, int.Parse(txt_server_port.Text)); mainSocket.Bind(endpoint); mainSocket.Listen(100); mainSocket.BeginAccept(new AsyncCallback(ConnetedClient), mainSocket);

Comment: just using a asychnorous sockets

Comment: all clients are to connect automatic

Answer (score 0):

If all your clients are trying to connect together it might be that the listener backlog got filled.
You can increase the backlog in the parameter passed to the `Listen` method.

Comment: My socket backlog is 100 in listening. I to need to increase or decrease.

Comment: if your backlog is 100 and you got only 10-15 connections this is not the problem.

Comment: all clients are to connect automatic